# Checking a checkbox based on array value?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, foreach

I currently have two arrays that look like this:

Swatches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [swatch_id] => 8
            [swatch_file] => orange_swatch.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [swatch_id] => 9
            [swatch_file] => pink_swatch.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [swatch_id] => 10
            [swatch_file] => green_swtach.jpg
        )

)
```

Selected Swatches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [swatches_has_products_id] => 18
            [swatches_swatch_id] => 8
            [products_product_id] => 19
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [swatches_has_products_id] => 19
            [swatches_swatch_id] => 10
            [products_product_id] => 19
        )

)
```

I am trying to check a check box if `$swatch['swatch_id']` is equal to `$selected_swatches['swatches_swatch_id']`. I am doing this with the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($swatches as $k => $swatch): ?>
    <li>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/images/swatches/<?php echo $swatch['swatch_file']; ?>" height=""/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product_has_swatch[]" value="<?php echo $swatch['swatch_id']; ?>" <?php    if($swatch['swatch_id'] == $selected_swatches[$k]['swatches_swatch_id']) : ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> />
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However I get the following error, if there are no matches:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
   Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined offset: 2
   Filename: products/create.php
Line Number: 137
```

Line 137 is the `if` to check if I have matches; Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is:

```
// make a new array of selected ids
$newArr = array();
foreach($selected_swatches as $val) {
    array_push($newArr, $val['swatches_swatch_id']);
}

// then check with in_array, like:
<?php foreach ($swatches as $k => $swatch): ?>
    <li>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/images/swatches/<?php echo $swatch['swatch_file']; ?>" height=""/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product_has_swatch[]" value="<?php echo $swatch['swatch_id']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($swatch['swatch_id'], $newArr)) : ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> />
    </li>
<?php endforeach; >
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

because you don't have index 2 in **Selected Swatches** array.. thats why it is giving you notice .

Answer (score 0):

```
**Check this out it works fine**

$swatches           = array( 0 =>array('swatch_id'=>8,'swatch_file'=>'orange_swatch.jpg'),
                             1 => array('swatch_id'=>9,'swatch_file'=>'ping_swatch.jpg'),
                             2 =>array('swatch_id'=>10,'swatch_file'=>'green_swatch.jpg')
                           );
$selected_swatches  = array( 0 =>array('swatches_has_products_id'=>18,'swatches_swatch_id'=>8,'products_product_id'=>19),
                             1 =>array('swatches_has_products_id'=>19,'swatches_swatch_id'=>10,'products_product_id'=>19),

                            );               

foreach($swatches as $k=>$swatch) :

    ?>

<li>

 <input type="checkbox" name="product_has_swatch" value="<?php echo $swatch['swatch_id'];?>"

 <?php 
      if($swatch['swatch_id'] == $selected_swatches[$k]['swatches_swatch_id']):
              echo "checked = 'checked'";
      endif;
  ?>


 />
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```